# Unit Testing Controller that uses AutoMapper

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

I am attempting to Unit Test the following controller code in my MVC application.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index(string sort)
    {
      IEnumerable<Artist> artists;
      if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        artists = _artistService.GetArtistsForUser(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort) && sort != "asc")
        {
          ViewBag.Sort = "desc";
          artists = artists.OrderByDescending(a => a.FName);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        artists = _artistService.GetArtists(false);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort) && sort != "asc")
        {
          ViewBag.Sort = "desc";
          artists = artists.OrderByDescending(a => a.FName);
        }
      }

      var vm = new ArtistIndexVM { Artists = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Artist>, IEnumerable<ArtistVM>>(artists) };
      return View(vm);
    }
```

Notice that just before the final return statement, I have an AutoMapper mapping. This is throwing an error when I attempt to run the Unit Test. The error is

> Test method Project.Controllers.ArtistControllerTests.Index_Get_ReturnsAViewResult threw exception: 
>   AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

What is the best way to resolve this without having to redefine the mappings once again in the Test Project? You know, in line with Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principles.

Comment: Where ever you do your mappings configurations should be made accessible to external caller so that it can be invoked by the unit test code before its execution.

Comment: So would you say it is best to have the mappings sitting inside their own project? This way I can simply reference that project whenever I need mapping configurations? And if I do that, do I need to do anything else to get my tests passing?

Comment: No they don't need their own project. Given that you are using MVC5 the assumption is that you have a Startup class that handles the configuration directly there. During unit test this startup is not being called. You probably don't want to setup everything in start up. So I was suggesting you isolate the AutoMapper configuration into something that you can call from your unit test.

Comment: The exception clearly states you are missing mapping configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call your Mapper.Initialize initialization before your unit tests. You should have a call to Mapper.Initialize in your app's startup, usually App_Start for MVC applications.

You only need to call Mapper.Initialize once, so a common approach is to put it in the static constructor of your startup.